# Filter data frame based on values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (df1) that looks like this:

```
       value 
loc1   10
loc2   1
loc3   2
loc4   12
loc5   14
loc6   3
loc7   4
```

I want to get a list of all id.'s that have a value >10.

This is my solution, but its not in the right format:

id_outlier = df1[df1 > 10]

```
           value 
    loc1   10
    loc2   NaN
    loc3   NaN
    loc4   12
    loc5   14
    loc6   NaN
    loc7   NaN
```

My desired output is:

```
loc1 
loc4 
loc5
```

Comment: Is the name of your column really `id.` and is that your index column?

Comment: No, it does not have a name, but is the index column

Comment: id_outlier = df1[df1 > 10].index may be a solution

Comment: df1[df1['value'] > 10].index

Comment: `df1[df1['value'] > 10].index.tolist()` to get it as ['loc1', ... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to use `value` property.

```
id_outlier = df1[df1.value >= 10]
```

You can also use `bracket` notation.

```
id_outlier = df1[df1['value'] >= 10]
```

As I saw from your question what you need is returning the list of `indexes` filtered by above condition statement. For this, you have to use `index` property.

```
id_outlier = df1[df1.value >= 10].index
```

Output

```
In[1]: id_outlier
Out[1]: Int64Index(['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5'],
       dtype='int64', length=3)
```

If you want to obtain a numpy array, just use `values` property.

```
id_outlier = df1[df1.value >= 10].index.values
```

or use `tolist` for obtaining a python list.

```
id_outlier = df1[df1.value >= 10].index.tolist()
```